# Conference call for interviews - too expensive

Tags: interviewing, phone

I have been given a phone number for my interview, using which and a reference number, I can connect to any number of interviewers in a room. The drawback for me with this is that I do not have a proper data plan with my provider for this call and I will be incurring enormous charges.

How do I communicate this appropriately to the interviewer? Should I offer alternatives like them calling me on my mobile number? Will that be appropriate?

EDIT: Wanted to add that the number provided to me was a 0330 number - both of us are based in the UK. I checked with my provider and the per minute costs are 20p, working out to £50 for a 2-hour interview - more than the cost of transport to that city!

Comment: Can you not just use wifi?

Comment: Is it the data or phone call costs that is the problem? Given the answer and the word "data plan" it sounds like the data limit, but from the rest of the question it sounds more like it is the minute cost for phone calls that is the problem. That would lead to different answers.

Comment: Is it normal in your region that you call employer for interview? I've never had such interview.

Comment: I've had telephone interviews before, apparently to screen out people with good-looking resumes before in-person interviews.  I've never been hired without at least one in-person interview.

Comment: @Twyxz: Sorry how to make phone calls using WiFi? You mean PopTox?

Comment: 1 If they are using a premium rate number to interview id run away and 2 what does your "data" have to do with this you would be using your call minutes

Comment: @David Thornley The last time I was hired from an FTF interview was 1989. So in almost 30 years I've never had a successful FTF interview, which sounds bad, but there have not been that many, and I might be picky.

Answer (score 7):

It's completely reasonable to mention that what they are suggesting for an interview will be very expensive.  Suggest a few alternatives (Skype, the company calling you, etc).  If they are really interested in you they shouldn't be put off by this.  And if they are upset about it, you might not want to work for a company that is that rigid.

Comment: or that tight with money

Answer (score 3):

Find somewhere with WiFi that you can call from without impacting your data charges (you'll probably get a better connection anyway).

If you tell them that the data charges are a concern to you, you're in danger of appearing to be a bit desperate (or cheap).

Or simply buy a data bundle for your phone - paying for data upfront is usually a lot cheaper than paying fees when you blow your limit.

Comment: I didn't understand - how will WiFi help to make calls?

Comment: @Jara Smartphones (eg. Android, iPhone, etc.) can make calls over the internet using WiFi, which avoids the phone company's data usage.

Answer (score 2):

Figure it out! This is a relatively easy problem to solve and not being able to do so, could make you look incompetent. Options include

- Make sure that the access number you have isn't already toll free. Most conference call services offer toll free access numbers
- WIFI
- Skype calling using your laptop and headset. You can upload a few bucks on yoru skype account and use it to call numbers anyhere in the world for very little money
- Get an international access plan from a third party provider. These are available for most countries to most countries and can be "pay as you go". I can call Germany from any phone in the US for 1c/minute using something like https://deutschlandanrufen.com/ (not affiliated, no endorsement intended)
- Borrow a phone from a friend or family member that have an unlimited access plan or enough to share.
- Buy a one time data package from provider

Comment: +1 for the get a Skype account with outbound calling if the cell phone plan is that unworkable.

Comment: Yes thanks, Skype calling didn't occur to me, will check the rates.